# CSS: Background img not centering

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I open the HTML file the background img is centered but after uploading the files to Wordpress the background is centered to the right of the screen. I'm at a lost for what the problem could be.

here's the code

```
body {
line-height: 1;
background:url(images/shopbg.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: 80%;
background-position: center center;
background-color: black;
```

Comment: Welcome! Please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is not enough information here to solve your problem. This is a CSS fragment, but CSS is applied to HTML which we do not have here, and as you stated it is affected by a file upload (i.e. WordPress, which is PHP).

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to this so if possible can you tell me what information/code i should provide for a clearer understanding of my problem. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Your styling is applied to the `<body>` tag and when you are uploading your file you probably have other css files with classes on the `<body>`. You could create a specific class for your element and apply the styling there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice i'll try that out right away and see how it turns out

Answer (score 0):

try create div and put the image and add a class to manage the image, or you need to see the image type background???

Comment: html :<div>
   <img class="bgimg" src="image">
  </div>

Comment: if you just want the image to be centered, apply the style to the image directly css:  img {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 255px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 99%;
}

Comment: or create a class for your image thats is better